# WSO2 Identity Server: Storing user password as PlainText

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am creating user using UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub, but Identity store saves the user password as Plain Text, but user-mgt.xml has SHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this must be due to configuration issue defined in [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2281). Could you please try to change the configuration as following, i.e with capital `P` and restart the server. Then try to create a new user and see

`<Property name="PasswordHashMethod">SHA</Property>`